# To find a URL for 404 not found in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find if a file exists or not. My Server do not report a 404, rather it simply redirect to a custom 404 page and return 302 (redirect) or something similar. My scenario is try the first URL, if the file doesnt exists or not valid then show the alternate URL. My script is as follows:

```
$filename= 'http://35.164.39.39/quote1.pdf';
$handle = curl_init($filename);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($handle);

    /* If the document has loaded successfully without any redirection or error */
    if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {
       $new_url = 'http://34.219.140.48/quote1.pdf';
    } else {
    $new_url = 'http://35.164.39.39/quote1.pdf';
    }
```

And then i will call the new_url:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $new_url; ?>">Quote</a>
```

I can see with the above code is it always takes the $filename condition as true and loads this URL. Can anyone suggest me how to handle this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can anyone pls help me on the same. Thx

Comment: No one to help me?

Comment: Maybe, replace '$new_url' var name by '$filename' ? (if you recall your function)

Comment: Let me check it. Thank you

Comment: If i call $filename, then everytime the url will not change. Thats wat i guess. i just checked but its incorrect.

Comment: Is there any other approach?

Comment: where $new_url  is used ? only in php html returned ?

Comment: For example this is the correct test attachment. http://34.219.140.47/core/enquiry_note_upload/uploads/3e110c27-93c5-4b08-a384-32f1c9172133/_1549271714_test_pdf.pdf, If this file doesnt exist then the new_url should be http://35.164.39.38/core/enquiry_note_upload/uploads/3e110c27-93c5-4b08-a384-32f1c9172133/_1549271714_test_pdf.pdf, which means just the ip address need to be changed, rest the url is same.

Comment: Yes i use $new_url only in the php html returned.

Comment: ok and $new_url is already 'http://35.164.39.39/quote1.pdf' it's correct ?

Comment: Yes its correct.

Comment: Can you check http response code ?

Comment: @Sanju : Give my below code a try

Comment: Let me check it @Mujeebu.

Comment: Sure! I just tested it OK. Let me know if any issues. @Sanju

Comment: @Sanju - Have you got it?

Comment: Yes i got it. Both of your answers are working @Meejeebu and Aborted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$proto = "http://";
$uri = "/quote1.pdf"; 

$success = $proto."34.219.140.48".$uri;
$failed = $proto."35.164.39.39".$uri;

$handle = curl_init($success);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($handle);

/* If the document has NOT loaded successfully without any redirection or error */
if ($httpCode !== 200) {
   echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"<?php echo $failed; ?>\">Quote</a>";
}else{
   echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"<?php echo $success; ?>\">Quote</a>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $url = 'http://34.219.140.48/quote1.pdf';
    $url1 = 'http://35.164.39.39/quote1.pdf';

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    /* Check if not 200 */
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpCode !== 200) {
        $url = $url1;
    }

    curl_close($handle);
    echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">Quote</a>";
```

Comment: @Aborted-Security I hope he only needs whether it's a success / not.

Comment: Yes sorry, i have delete my comment. You are rigth